# FireFox InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object

Tags: javascript, firefox

Hi I have a really odd problem. We have a lot of users in our application and a single user is experiencing an issue I cannot replicate on any other machine (I've tested 7 machines, 2 Win10, 5 Macbooks, in both FF 42 and FF ESR).

InvalidAccessError: A parameter or an operation is not supported by the underlying object

```
getRule: function( aSelector ) {
    var rules = ( this._rules.cssRules ) ? this._rules.cssRules : this._rules.rules,
        rule = false,
        i, len;

    try {
        for ( i = 0, len = rules.length; i < len; i++ ) {
            if ( rules[ i ] && rules[ i ].selectorText == aSelector ) {
                rule = rules[ i ];
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch( ex ) { }

    return rule;
},
```

How I'm creating the stylesheet:

```
    this._container = document.createElement( 'style' );
    this._container.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/css' );
    this._container.setAttribute( 'rel', 'stylesheet' );
    this._container.setAttribute( 'media', 'all' );

    document.getElementsByTagName( 'head' )[ 0 ].appendChild( this._container );
    this._rules = document.styleSheets[ document.styleSheets.length - 1 ];
```

When it tries to access rules.length that error shows up but only for this one person. The CSS rules I'm accessing are rules I'm dynamically generating including the stylesheet tag itself (same domain so not a CORS issue).

Originally I didn't have the try/catch and adding it didn't help. During testing this user did have NoScript installed which is what I thought was the problem but they have since removed it. They said they've tested multiple machines and it happens on them all but I can't replicate it on any machine I've tried.

What else could cause this message? Are there any browser settings that could cause this? Or addons? I've asked them to uninstall all addons and refresh FireFox and neither helped.

Comment: FF 45? you tested with nightly? - is there a line number associated with the error?

Comment: have you asked them to use a different browser?

Comment: read the first comment at https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=761236 - sounds like this could be related

Comment: I saw that. Why would that only happen to a single user in only one browser?

Comment: timing is a wonderful pain in the butt :D - is there any way you can refactor your code to wait on the 'load' event when loading the stylesheet

Comment: All of this is inside document.ready, the code I posted is part of a class and the stylesheet is created (empty) in the constructor. Then code creates rules which use the getRule method to see if they exist so it can either insert or update the rule.

I added a console.log to show the stylesheet it's accessing and asked the user to screenshot their console. I'm starting to think something on their computer is injecting a stylesheet and the one I'm reading isn't the one I think I am.

Comment: I think `this._rules = this._container.sheet;` instead of the way you are doing it would assure you have the correct rules - but I haven't tested it

Comment: Good call, I changed it to that to see if it helps. Waiting on user I'll reply when I hear back from them.